# how to set up rejectUnauthorized in parse.com httpRequest method

Tags: http, parse-platform

I'm getting

```
 Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with given CA certificates;
```

error while sending `Parse.Cloud.httpRequest`

how cat I set up

```
rejectUnauthorized
```

option here?

Comment: Can you post the code that's giving you the error?

Comment: is the certificate self-signed?